# Why can't I access someone's Instagram account if they have not blocked me?

Tags: instagram, user-accounts

Instagram now deletes all comments and likes from a user that is blocked. So I can't find or access the Instagram account today that I gave some beneficial comments to just a few days ago. From another friends account I can still see my comments to this person's post, so they didn't block me (I think). What might be happening? Is it possible Instagram blocks users from individual accounts? Does anyone have an idea?